# Find unique and overlapping subscribers from list that also uses timestamped actions to track status

Tags: sql

I have one table that tracks all subscribers to various lists. It looks like: list_id, user_id, action_date, action. Users subscribe to a list ID and we capture that with a time stamp and action=1. If they unsubscribe we timestamp a new entry and capture action=0.

We launched a few new subscriptions recently and I'm trying to figure out:

1. How many users are subscribed to list_id A and list_id B
2. How many users are subscribed to just list_id A and not list_id B (and vice versa)

I am still new to SQL so throwing in the wrinkle where the most recent action for each user_id must be the action of 1 is throwing me off.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: And what RDBMS?  There are some better options available in some of them.

Comment: Nothing with success. I am not expert enough at SQL to know how to structure the query to count only the user_ids where the most recent action_date has an action that equals 1 and not 0.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need is to get actual state for each subscription. You can get this in a statement like that (in vanilla SQL, you didn't specify exact server):

```
select a.user_id, a.list_id, a.last_date, a.action
into #tmp
from Actions a
  join 
  (
    select user_id, list_id, MAX(action_date) last_date
    from Actions
    where list_id in ('A', 'B')
    group by user_id, list_id
  ) b
  on a.user_id = b.user_id
    and a.list_id = b.list_id
    and a.action_date = b.last_date
```

In a subquery 'b' we get maximum action_date for each user_id and list_id. Then we have to join back to main table to catch status. Result stored in temporary table #tmp.

Then you can find answers on question 1 and 2 in many different ways. For example,
'How many users are subscribed to list_id A and list_id B'

```
select distinct user_id 
from #tmp t1
where 
  exists (
    select 1 
    from #tmp t2 
    where t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
      and t1.list_id = t2.list_id
      and t2.list_id = 'A' 
      and t2.status = 1
      )
  and exists (
    select 1 
    from #tmp t3 
    where t1.user_id = t3.user_id 
      and t1.list_id = t3.list_id
      and t3.list_id = 'B' 
      and t3.status = 1
      )
```

How many users are subscribed to just list_id A and not list_id B

```
select distinct user_id 
from #tmp t1
where 
  exists (
    select 1 
    from #tmp t2 
    where t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
      and t1.list_id = t2.list_id
      and t2.list_id = 'A' 
      and t2.status = 1
      )
  and **not** exists (
    select 1 
    from #tmp t3 
    where t1.user_id = t3.user_id 
      and t1.list_id = t3.list_id
      and t3.list_id = 'B' 
      and t3.status = 1
      )
```

and vice versa

```
select distinct user_id 
from #tmp t1
where 
  **not** exists (
    select 1 
    from #tmp t2 
    where t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
      and t1.list_id = t2.list_id
      and t2.list_id = 'A' 
      and t2.status = 1
      )
  and exists (
    select 1 
    from #tmp t3 
    where t1.user_id = t3.user_id 
      and t1.list_id = t3.list_id
      and t3.list_id = 'B' 
      and t3.status = 1
      )
```

I've used this form because all statements looks similar and can be changed easily. Depending on your server and exact table definition there are ways to formulate answers in a shorter way. For example, for SQL Server I'd prefer to use ROW_NUMBER to get actual states of subscriptions. First question can be answered like this:

```
select user_id 
from #tmp
where 
  list_id in ('A', 'B')
  and status = 1
group by user_id
having COUNT(*) = 2
```

I didn't check statements on real data so there can be errors. I've tried to show idea.